# ¿Por qué o para qué se utiliza "_" al principio de nombres de variable de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables

¿En qué casos y por qué se utilizan en JavaScript nombres de variable que empiezan por `_`?

Por ejemplo:

```
var _ejemplo = 1
```

Comment: He visto que lo hacen, me nacio la duda y no encontre una respuesta concisa.

Comment: Bienvenido Carlosadev, el uso de este prefijo es subjetivo, depende de uno mismo si quiere usarlo como convención. Se usa habitualmente para identificar las propiedades privadas de una clase, con esto se da a entender el alcance que tiene una propiedad de tal forma que el desarrollador sepa, a simple vista con que datos pueda o no trabajar fuera de la clase. Su uso no cambia en nada la forma en la que el interprete trabaja, lo toma como una variable mas. *Te lo dejo como comentario por su misma subjetividad, no es una regla estricta de programación, y no te causará problemas si no lo usas.*

Comment: Saludo @Carlosadev . Bienvenido a nuestra comunidad de stack Overflow. como te menciono anterior mente nuestro compañero Victor Hugo Tirado. Todo depende para que tu quieres utilizar tus variables y llevar esa conversión de variable. otro lo utilizan para resaltar una variable importarte o otra funcionalidades que este programador le quieres dar. Por Ejemplo :** let miVariable = 'Hola Mundo'; ** o let mivariable = 'Hola Mundo'; . te recomiendo que entre a este [enlace](https://medium.com/@alonsus91/convenci%C3%B3n-de-nombres-desde-el-camelcase-hasta-el-kebab-case-787e56d6d023) de Conversión

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Como te han comentado todos, no es una norma el uso de `_` delante de un nombre de variable, se basa en estilos de código y en nomenclaturas (que no tienen por qué seguirse, no son regla sintáctica del lenguaje). Como mucho hay proposiciones (como han comentado en una respuesta) para poder implementar campos privados en javascript (ECMAScript), pero no tiene relación alguna con el prefijo `_`, si no con `#` (que actualmente no es un carácter válido de comienzo de variable), y ni tan siquiera se sabe si se llegará a implementar.

Comment: Gracias por responder

Answer (score 1):

Es solo para *INDICAR* que una variable es de uso privado. En JavaScript esto al menos aún no existe como tal, pero está la propuesta:

En este enlace verás la propuesta sobre el uso de variables privadas. Si lo quieres usar puedes buscar en babel algún plugin que interprete este código y lo pase a es2015.
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields

Ahora, no es recomendable usar `_` como primer caracter de una variable en javascript.

Comment: Que tal Diego... Seria bueno que te des una vuelta por [answer] para poder mejorar tu respuesta... Para poder entender como funciona el sitio te recomiento vayas hagas un [tour]...

Comment: Hola Deigo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Tienes razón @VíctorHugoTirado. Gracias! :)

Comment: Creo que la proposición era usar `#` (y no `_`) para marcar campos privados. [Ver proposición](https://tc39.es/proposal-private-fields/). Usar `#ejemplo` sería una versión corta de `this.#ejemplo`.